# ANOVA: Many individual tests versus one big model

Tags: anova, modeling, interaction

I aim to use ANOVA to test the main effect of a categorical IV (3 levels) on a continuous DV. Additionally, however, I have six other variables (categorical and continuous) that might play a role here. I would like to test for each of them whether they moderate the effect of IV on DV, but I am not interested in interactions that happen between these moderating factors.

Is it statistically sound to conduct six different two-way ANOVAs (each including IV and one of the moderators) or do I have to integrate all variables into one model? I tried it on some dummy data and I see that results vary slightly between these two approaches.